# How can I hide street names in Google Maps JS API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to remove all the street names and pins of various places (e.g. museums, restaurants, and other spots) in Google Maps by using JS API.

Basically, all I need is just a map with no labels at all.

I assume it should be possible. How can I achieve it?

Here is the image of what I want to remove for better clarification.

[image]

Comment: Just take a look at working example https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/hiding-features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can hide the labels which you don't require to display in map

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.86, lng: 151.209},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeControl: false
        });
          map.setOptions({styles: styles['hide']});
      }

      var styles = {
        hide: [
          {
            featureType: 'poi.business',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
          },
          {
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'labels.icon',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
          }
        ]
      };

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Still you can have granule control on the label type, to know more about all styles just read  here: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Do upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: Actually I did, but I don't know why it doesn´t add the upvote. It just makes the "up" button orange. Not sure why it is not working :/